# CloudKit Dashboard index queryable, sortable and searchable

Tags: indexing, cloudkit

I need to be able to search a field of type NSString in CloudKit records. I found a comment saying that there used to be a searchable index type for fields. Now there are only queryable and sortable. What do I set the index type for the field in order to be able to search for a specific string in a field in all the records?

Also, does one option include the other? I mean is one of the options inclusive of the other? For example, if I choose queryable, does that mean the field is also sortable, whereas when I choose sortable it only makes it sortable but not queryable? Or if I want to choose both, would I have to create separate indexes, one for queryable and one for sortable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still set the index type to searchable, there are 3 types: Queryable, Sortable and Searchable.

One option does not include the other, so yes you will have to create separate indexes if you wish to have the field queryable and sortable.

Comment: It only shows queryable and sortable in CloudKit Dashboard. That must mean that I need to set searchable indexes in code. Am I correct?

Comment: No. Can you give me an idea of what record type and record field you are dealing with?

Comment: It's a custom record type with a field called "text" of type String that I need to be able to be able to search within in a query.

Comment: That custom field is it a reference to some other record type?

Comment: No, the field is of type string. It's what I will search. It is not a reference.

Comment: I just created a custom field of type string and I was able to set all three indexes. I would suggest you post some screenshots of how you have set up everything.

Comment: I just checked my "text" field. I see that I am able to select from all three index types. I made a silly mistake. I had seen that for the recordName field only index types were available. Thanks for your help. How should I mark this post?

Comment: No worries, glad I could help!